# Improve performance in Google App Script Search functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written a script using Google App Script (in javascript) and I am looking for a way to be best optimize function that return objects, based on one or more search fields.  The data is stored in a Google Sheet.  The UI I have passes parameters to my function, then I iterate over a given sheet to find rows that meet a criteria, and add cells to an object, to be returned.  The return could be just one object or a list of objects.  For the most part, this works fine, but if I have this type of function nested in a loop it can really drag the performance.  Any advise on how to improve performance would be greatly appreciated.  Here is an example of my code:

```
function GetAllReportByOrgID_DataLayer_(org_id, reporting_periods) {
    //get all reporting period for program
    var rows = GetDataRows_(DATA_SPREAD_SHEET_ID, RESPONSE_PAGE);
    var surveys = [];   
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var found_org_id = row[2];
        var found_is_active = row[13];
        if (found_org_id == org_id && found_is_active == true ) {
            var survey = {};
            survey.indicator_id = row[0];
            survey.program_id = row[1];
            survey.org_guid = row[2];
            survey.survey_response = row[3];
            survey.reporting_period = row[5];
            survey.reporting_period_name = GetReportingPeriodNameById_(row[5], reporting_periods);
            survey.is_final_report = row[6];
            survey.is_submitted = row[7];
            survey.submitted_by = row[8];
            survey.submitted_by_email = row[9];
            survey.date_created = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[10]);
            survey.date_updated = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[11]);
            survey.fiscal_year = row[12];
            survey.documents = GetDocumentsById_DataLayer_({
                 program_id: row[13]
            });
            surveys.push(survey);
        }
    }
    surveys.success = true;
    return surveys;
}
function GetDataRows_(Sheet_Id, SheetName) {
    var sheet = GetSheet_(Sheet_Id, SheetName);
    var rows = [];
    if (sheet) {
        rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    }
    return rows;
}
function GetSheet_(Sheet_Id, SheetName) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Sheet_Id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);
  return sheet;
}
function GetReportingPeriodNameById_(id, reporting_periods) {
   if (id) {
       for (var i = 0; i < reporting_periods.length; i++) {
           if (reporting_periods[i].id == id) {
              return reporting_periods[i].value
           }
        }
      return "Reporting Period Not Found"
  } else {
    return "Reporting Period Not Found"
 }
}

function GetDocumentsById_DataLayer_(data) {
    var rows = GetDataRows_(DATA_SPREAD_SHEET_ID, PROGAM_DOCUMENTS_PAGE);
    var documents = [];
    var program_id = data.program_id.trim();

    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var found_program_id = row[1];
        var is_active = row[6];
    if(is_active === true){
      if (found_program_id === program_id) {
        var document = {};
        document.document_id = row[0];
        document.program_id = row[1];
        document.document_name = row[2];
        document.file_id = row[3];
        document.file_name = row[4];
        document.file_url = row[5]
        document.date_created = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[7]);
        document.date_updated = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[8]);
        documents.push(document);
      }
    }       
    }
    documents.success = true;
    return documents;
}

function ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(unix_timestamp) {
    if (!unix_timestamp) {
        return "";
    }
    var a = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var year = a.getFullYear();
    var month = months[a.getMonth()];
    var date = a.getDate();
    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    var sec = a.getSeconds();
    var time = a.getMonth() + "/" + date + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    return time;
}
```

This code mostly works fine, except when it is in a loop that gets called 100 times or so, then things lag and can take a minute or more to process.  The sheets aren't that big, less that 200 rows and 15 columns.
thanks

Comment: Your question is too general.  The typical answer will be read and implement best practices and come back if you need additional help.  You seem to have several helper functions that I would include in one function just to save time.

Comment: `ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[7]);` is undefined

Comment: @Cooper I didnt think it was worth putting in, as is just converts Unix time.  I can add it.  but the bigger issue seems to be the nested call.

Comment: Whatever you provide should meet the requirements of [mcve].  I would say that you should remove all helper functions especially if they call other functions to minimize the runtime.

Comment: Are you using a HTML page and is calling the server-side functions in apps script? And regarding this `function nested in a loop it can really drag the performance` is the loop in your client-side? As mentioned by @Cooper, I would appreciate it if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to verify if the possible proposed solution will improve your current performance. I am basically curious where does the nested loop happens

Comment: @RonM Yes, there is an HTML pagethat calls this function.  The code I posted is all being run on the server side.  There is a call from the client side to this function but all it does is pass a parameter.  Upon response, I take the data and display it.  The nested loop I am referring to is in the first function, at " survey.documents".  It calls a function "GetDocumentsById_DataLayer_" which is provided in the example as well.  I am happy to provide more info, but I am not sure how I can make this reproducible as it requires being run on the server and connecting to a Google Sheet.

Comment: I could set up a google sheet if that would be helpful?

Comment: yes please with the sample set of data

Comment: OK, sorry it took a while to clean the data.  You can see everything here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16eVZZEg93xD2pRawLQoCRxuRvRzqoOZ9KdL1rKde01c/edit#gid=251221706

Comment: When you open the document, make a copy to your local Google Account.  You can access the code by going to Tools->Script Editor

Answer (score 2):

The reason for performance depreciation is the `GetDataRows_` function, because it makes repeated calls to `Spreadsheet.openById()`, `ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);`. You could try using a global [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to cache these objects.  For example, Use a `Spreadsheet` map

```
const globalSSMap = new Map();//global SS map
```

Then your getter functions can be rewritten. For eg, to get `ss`, use

```
if(!globalSSMap.has(Sheet_id)) globalSSMap.set(Sheet_id,SpreadsheetApp.openById(Sheet_Id));
var ss = globalSSMap.get(Sheet_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I implemented the change you suggested.  It helped to shave off a couple of seconds but not much for than that.  Still, every bit helps.  thanks

Comment: @jason That's only a sample strategy. You need to implement the same for `sheet` and `rows` for massive improvements.

Answer (score 0):

### You can refer to this sample code:

**Data_Layer.gs**

```
function GetAllDataByManager_DataLayer_(loggedin_user) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREAD_SHEET_ID);

  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  // create sheet objects
  var sheetData = {};
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    sheetData[sheet.getName()] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  })

    var program_rows = sheetData[PROGRAM_MANAGERS];
    var ip_ids = [];
    var Company_data = [];
  var runtimeCountStart = new Date();

  //first search to make sure logged in user exists, and is marked as Active == True and is marked as an Admin
  //if they exist, add their ID to the list 
  //Should only see records for the logged in user if
  //they are either listed as the primary manager  (company tab)
  //or they are listed as an additional manager (program managers tab)

    for (var i = 1; i < program_rows.length; i++) {
        var row = program_rows[i];
        var found_admin_email = row[2];
        var found_is_active = row[10];
        if (found_admin_email == loggedin_user && found_is_active == true) {
            ip_ids.push(row[1])
        }
    }

  var partner_rows = sheetData[PARTNER_PAGE];  
  for (var i = 1; i < partner_rows.length; i++) {
    var partner_row = partner_rows[i]
    var found_partner_id = partner_row[0];
    var add_record = false;
    if(ip_ids.includes(found_partner_id)){
      add_record = true;
    }else{
      var found_cor_email = partner_row[5]
      if(loggedin_user.toUpperCase() == found_cor_email.toUpperCase()){
        add_record = true;
      }
    }    
    if(add_record == true){
      var partner = {
                    ip_id: partner_row[0],
                    ip_name: partner_row[1],
                    ip_poc_name: partner_row[2],
                    ip_poc_email: partner_row[3],
                    manager_name: partner_row[4],
                    manager_email: partner_row[5],
                    is_active: partner_row[6],
                    date_created: partner_row[7],
                    created_by: partner_row[8],
                    partner_programs:  GetAllProgramDataByIP_DataLayer_(sheetData, found_partner_id),  
          partner_notes: GetProgramNarrativesByPartnerID_DataLayer_(sheetData, found_partner_id),
          partner_reports: GetAllReportByPartnerID_DataLayer_(sheetData, found_partner_id)       
                };
                Company_data.push(partner)
    }

  }

  stop = new Date();
  newRuntime = Number(stop) - Number(runtimeCountStart);
  newRuntime  = (newRuntime /1000)/60

    return Company_data;

}
function GetAllProgramDataByIP_DataLayer_(sheetData, ip_id) {
    var rows = sheetData[PROGRAM_PAGE];
    var programs = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var found_partner_id = row[1];
        var program = {}
        if (found_partner_id === ip_id) {      
            program.program_id = row[0].toString();
            program.partner_id = row[1].toString();
            program.program_name = row[2].toString();
            program.program_country = row[3].toString();        
            program.program_background = row[4].toString();
            program.program_objectives = row[5].toString();
            program.program_justification = row[6].toString();
            program.program_start_date = row[7].toString();
      program.program_status = row[8].toString();
            program.program_contract_number = row[9].toString();            
            program.is_active = row[10]
            program.date_created = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[11].toString());
            program.date_updated = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[12].toString());
            program.success = true;
            programs.push(program)
        }

    }
    return programs;
}
function GetProgramNarrativesByPartnerID_DataLayer_(sheetData, partner_id) {
    var rows = sheetData[PROGRAM_NARRATIVE_NOTE];
    var programs_notes = [];
    var response = {};
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var found_partner_id = row[2];
        var is_active = row[7];
    if(is_active === true){
      if (found_partner_id === partner_id) {
        var note = {};
        note.note_id = row[0];
        note.program_id = row[1];
        note.company_guid = row[2];        
        note.note_title = htmlEscape_(row[3]);
        note.note_desc = htmlEscape_(row[4]);
        note.note_reportingPeriod = row[5];
        note.activity_theme = row[6];
        note.date_created = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[8]);
        note.date_updated = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[9]);
        programs_notes.push(note);
      }
    }       
    }
    response.success = true;
    response.programs_notes = programs_notes
    return response;
}
function GetAllReportByPartnerID_DataLayer_(sheetData, partner_id) {
    //get all reporting period for program
    var rows = sheetData[RESPONSE_PAGE];  
    var surveys = [];   
    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        var found_partner_id = row[2];
        if (found_partner_id == partner_id) {
            var survey = {};
            survey.indicator_id = row[0];
            survey.program_id = row[1];
            survey.company_guid = row[2];
            survey.survey_response = row[3];
            survey.reporting_period = row[5];
            survey.is_final_report = row[6];
            survey.is_submitted = row[7];
            survey.submitted_by = row[8];
            survey.submitted_by_email = row[9];
            survey.date_created = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[10]);
            survey.date_updated = ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(row[11]);
            survey.fiscal_year = row[12];
            surveys.push(survey);
        }
    }
    surveys.success = true;
    return surveys;
}
```

**Helper_Functions.gs**

```
function ConvertUnixTimeStampToDateTime_(unix_timestamp) {
    if (!unix_timestamp) {
        return "";
    }
    var a = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var year = a.getFullYear();
    var month = months[a.getMonth()];
    var date = a.getDate();
    var hour = a.getHours();
    var min = a.getMinutes();
    var sec = a.getSeconds();
    var time = a.getMonth() + "/" + date + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    return time;
}

function CreateGUID_() {
    return Utilities.getUuid();
}
function htmlEscape_(str) {
  str = str.toString();
    if (str && str.length > 0) {
        return str.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, "")
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

### Note:

- I didn't see `GetDocumentsById_DataLayer_` and `survey.documents` in the shared script.
- I just looked for something to improve in your main function `GetAllDataByManager_DataLayer_()` where nested loop occur when you are checking your `partner_rows` variable.
- I don't think there's any more we can do regarding your nested loop check.

### Modifications Done:

- Although you prevented repeating the calls for `Spreadsheet.openById()`, you still make individual calls when you map your sheet objects since you use `ss.getSheetByName(SheetName);` to get individual sheet object based on the `SheetName` and even reading the sheet values during every loop for 3 different sheets
- What I did is to get all your sheet object available in your spreadsheet using `getSheets()`, get its data range values then map them based on their sheet name. As what was suggested by @TheMaster in the other answer
- Remove unnecessary functions in `Helper_Functions.gs`

### Execution Log:

[image]

- For the code changes, refer to the last 2 recent Web Apps execution logs. Compare it to the first execution

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues during your implementation so I could update the answer accordingly